# TCP port keeps changing with perl LWP in loop

Tags: perl, port-number

I'm analyzing a small LWP useragent in a loop with an HTTP analyzer and I noticed that every visit of the URL my port keeps changing.

While I have a small script also made in VB.Net `httpwebrequest` and that isn't changing my port number while visiting the URL 10 times.

Is it possible to keep a static ip:port while using perl?

Comment: ok, we've determined that your VB.net script is using keepalive (so only establishing a single connection and then reusing it), but your LWP script is not (so each connection gets a new local port).  And that you seem to be having problems getting LWP to use keepalive.  So at this point I wonder *why* you care?  A new local port for new connections is nothing wrong or unusual, and keepalive is nice for efficiency (at least when it doesn't *cause* problems) but doesn't sound critical in your case.  What actual problem are you trying to solve now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the HTTP client:

```
use LWP::Protocol::http qw( );

@LWP::Protocol::http::EXTRA_SOCK_OPTS = (
    LocalPort => $port,
);
```

If you also want to use a specific interface,

```
@LWP::Protocol::http::EXTRA_SOCK_OPTS = (
    LocalAddr => $ip,
    LocalPort => $port,
);
```

Of course, you run into problems if the port is already in use, which is likely if you just used it for another connection.

```
use LWP::Protocol::http qw( );
use LWP::UserAgent      qw( );

my $port = 12456;
@LWP::Protocol::http::EXTRA_SOCK_OPTS = (
    LocalPort => 12456,
);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
print $ua->get('http://www.example.com/show_port')->content for 1..2;
```

Output:

```
>script.pl
12456
Can't connect to www.example.com:80 (10048)

LWP::Protocol::http::Socket: connect: 10048 at .../LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.

>perl -E"say $^E=10048"
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

More likely, the port is not being reused, the connection is. You could also try reusing the connection by passing `keep_alive => 1` to the LWP::UserAgent constructor.

```
use LWP::UserAgent qw( );

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( keep_alive => 1 );
print $ua->get('http://www.example.com/show_port')->content for 1..2;
```

Output:

```
57842
57842
```

Comment: You might want to `local`ize those package vars.

Comment: ok im not a great coder at all, im in the beginning of learning but i can't seem to get it working. According to the analyzer it keeps changing the port. I tried it also with the keep alive but that dont work :(

Comment: @user1796805: is VB.net using keepalive?  you should be able to tell from your analyzer

Comment: Contrary to what you said, the code I posted does work as I described. See update.

Comment: @ysth yes its keeping alive in vb.net according to the analyzer and it dont change the number.

Comment: @ikegami strange thing is i can only use the script.pl on time, after using it dont run anymore only if i change the LocalPort it does it again

Comment: "dont run anymore" means what?

Comment: @ysth i mean i can hit the script only 1 time and analyze it, after using the script i cant run it for another time could u put it in loop so i can see when running multiple time if the port stays the same. Sorry for asking so much but i cant get it working properly :(

Comment: @user1796805, I know. all that is covered in my post. In detail. What's your point?

Comment: @ysth, The port is put in TIMED_WAIT after the first request, so it's not available for the second request if it comes too soon afterwards.